# How do I download a file from a calendar event?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to download a file from a calendar event in web forms but it is not working.

```
events: 
[
    {
        title: 'All Day Event',
        start: new Date(y, m, 1)
    },
    {
        title: 'Click for File',
        start: new Date(y, m, 28),
        end: new Date(y, m, 29),
        url: 'C:\\Users\\Dev\\Documents\\testing.txt',
        select: function Download(url) {
            document.getElementById('my_iframe').src = url;
        },
        className: 'success'
    }
]
```

The event is in the calendar but when trying to download it doesn't do anything?

Can someone please assist?

Thanks

Comment: Download what, exactly? What you've posted is executable client JavaScript - not JSON.

Comment: I need to download a file from the server when clicking on the event in the calendar.  Sort of like a file button download, but use it as an event click